# Windows Batch Script : for loop not printing * values

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch script line like below :

```
for %%v in (aa bb* cc) do echo mget %%v
```

I am getting output as :

```
mget aa

mget cc
```

But I need output as :

```
mget aa 

mget bb*

mget cc
```

**Update**

I have a batch file called ftp.bat and a parameter file called `parm.txt`.  `parm.txt` looks like:

```
server=xxx.yyy.com
user=abc
pwd=xyz
files=aa bb* cc dd ------(this varies)
```

I need to extract these values in my batch file to construct ftp commands.  Using delim concept I've got server, user, pwd but I need to separate the files.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `for` with a wildcard, the interpreter looks for all files matching the wildcard ("bb*" in this case) and passes the names of the files to your command.  It won't pass a string containing a '*' (or a '?') to your command.

Instead, create a text file called `filelist.txt` containing:

```
aa
bb*
cc
```

and use the command:

```
for /F %%I in (filelist.txt) do echo mget %%I
```

**Update**

Apparently, there is already a `filelist.txt` with multiple items on each line.  Create a batch file called `vary.bat`:

```
@echo off
:more
if "%1"=="" (goto finished)
echo mget %1
shift
goto more
:finished
```

This takes a variable number of parameters and echoes an mget for each one.  Call it with something like:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%I in (filelist.txt) do vary %%I
```

**Another update**

This will read `parm.txt`, create a variable for each of `server`, `user`, `pwd` and `files`, then call `vary.bat` (described above) on the list of files.

```
for /F "delims== tokens=1,2" %%I in (parm.txt) do set %%I=%%J
vary %files%
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still have the problem. Yes, I have a seperate file as you said. But that file has variable(values) assigned with list of values like values=aa bb* cc . In this case it is echo'ing only first value which is aa.

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of values in each list, or does it vary?

Comment: And the number of values varies, it is dynamic.

Comment: Actually a separate file is not needed. You could have a subroutine call instead.

Comment: Added above the Question2. Need actually the exact code piect as I do not understand much about windows batch scripting

Comment: @user1171858: Can you post a sample of the actual input file?  Add it to the end of your question.

Comment: As I haave mentioned above, parm.txt is the input file to batch file and it has 4 lines. 4th line has files parameter and with the values aa bb* cc dd in the same line.

Comment: @user1171858: Sorry, I didn't see your update to my question because the edit was pending.  I've added your info to the original question.  Plus, I've added another update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. For your solution, we need to have one more batch file (vary.bat). Cant we do the all coding in main batch script(ftp.bat) ??

Comment: @user1171858: Yes.  As AndriyM said, you can use a subroutine.  Copy the contents of vary.bat into the end of ftp.bat.  Prefix it with the label `:vary` and change `vary %files%` to `call :vary %files%`.

Comment: @user1171858: Make sure to add `goto :eof` just before the `:vary` line, to jump over the subroutine when the main script is done working, to avoid the unnecessary extra "call" of the subroutine.